# Gradient color sizes

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm still learning parts of gradients, and I want to accomplish something that would enable certain colors of gradients to be certain sizes.

**Example**
Let's say I have a gradient with 3 colors: red, purple, and blue, in that order, from top to bottom. I want red to be around for 10%, and purple as 80%, and blue again as 10%. I have tried to create this with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Srn5/), and it doesn't work out how I planned for it to. Along with the code I attempted to use, and the result is funky. In fact, the gradient isn't even a gradient any more, it's just goes from one color to another:

```
.gradient-square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 10%, purple 80%, blue 10%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red 10%, purple 80%, blue 10%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 10%, purple 80%, blue 10%);
    background: linear-gradient(red 10%, purple 80%, blue 10%);
}
```

**Accomplishing**
What I want to accomplish is to have a gradient that starts off having, say 10px of a color, and then at the bottom is another 10px of a different color, while in between those two colors will be a single color, so the size of the element doesn't affect the length of the gradients.

Thank you for your help ahead of time.

Comment: [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/AX3ky/) for original problem. Is the desired output [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AX3ky/2/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AX3ky/3/)?

Comment: The second "this" (where gradient transitions are shown) I suppose I didn't think about my percentages correctly with the gradients, thank you!

Comment: This tool proved useful many times for me: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution given by OP:

**----- SOLVED -----**
Thanks to @Joeytje50 for the help. I never thought towards how the percentages were actually used, and thank you. The correct way on what I was trying to accomplish ~ [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AX3ky/3/)

```
.gradient-square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 0%, purple 10%, purple 90%, blue 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red 0%, purple 10%, purple 90%, blue 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 0%, purple 10%, purple 90%, blue 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(red 0%, purple 10%, purple 90%, blue 100%);
}
```